# How to get data from a row of a table from a checkbox?

Tags: oracleforms

I have a table with many rows, and one of the columns has a checkbox for each row. How do I access the row data through these checkboxes when they are checked? Can anyone help me please??

Answer (score 0):

The "checkbox" is just a visual representation for the data it contains.  Consider that you can easily change the checkbox into a text field.  So, getting the value of the checkbox (for a single row item) is no different than getting the value from any other object.

```
myvariable := :block_name.checkbox_name;
```

However, for multi-row blocks getting the value is a bit more awkward because there is more than one of the same item.  Fortunately in newer versions of Forms, GET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY was extended to now include a property called "DATA_VALUE".  This allows you to get the value of the item from a specific row (e.g. current record).

```
myvariable := GET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY (:SYSTEM.CURSOR_RECORD, DATA_VALUE);
```

If you want to know when a particular checkbox was checked or unchecked, you can use the WHEN-CHECKBOX-CHANGED trigger.  Each time the checkbox is checked or unchecked this trigger will fire.  When it fires you can capture its current value.  Note that the "current" value will be the value after the user acted on it. So in this trigger you might have a line of code similar to the one above.

The latest version of [Forms](https://www.oracle.com/application-development/technologies/forms/forms.html) is 12.2.1.19.